# Can not change youtube livechat from top chat to live chat using Tampermonkey

Tags: javascript, youtube, tampermonkey

I'm trying to write a tampermonkey script to change youtube live chat from top to live chat.

I'm new to javascript, and this clicking answer while working in the browser console posted 1 by 1, it doesnt work like this.

I've tried using event with listbox options, as there is an element with the role "listbox", but inside of it were'nt options, so i couldn't get far with it, same with dropdown.

```js
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Youtube Live chat
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      0.1
// @description  LIVE chat
// @author       You
// @match        *youtube.com*
// @match        https://www.youtube.com/live_chat*
// @match        https://www.youtube.com/live_chat_replay*
// @icon         https://www.google.com/s2/favicons?sz=64&domain=youtube.com
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==

(function() {
'use strict';

    function main() {
        const menuButton = document.querySelector('div#trigger.style-scope.tp-yt-paper-menu-button');
        const liveOption = document.querySelector('tp-yt-paper-listbox#menu.dropdown-content.style-scope.yt-dropdown-menu').children[1];
        const topOption = document.querySelector('tp-yt-paper-listbox#menu.dropdown-content.style-scope.yt-dropdown-menu').children[0];

        const selectedOptionText = 'yt-simple-endpoint style-scope yt-dropdown-menu iron-selected';

        if (topOption.className == selectedOptionText) {
            menuButton.click();
            liveOption.click();
        }
    }

    window.addEventListener('load', main);
})();
```